# Purpose of TypeDependencyAttribute("System.SZArrayHelper") for IList<T>, IEnumerable<T> and ICollection<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

The comments provided in the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ilist.cs,b19f71a84062554b) for IList, IEnumerable and ICollection says

> Note that `T[] : IList<T>`, and we want to ensure that if you use
>    `IList<YourValueType>`, we ensure a `YourValueType[]` can be used 
>    without jitting.  Hence the `TypeDependencyAttribute` on `SZArrayHelper`.
>    This is a special hack internally though - see VM\compile.cpp.

Why does `IList<T>` contain a dependency on `SZArrayHelper`?. I understand that `SZArrayHelper` is a CLR wrapper around an array that implements the `IList<T>` interface but I do not get the full picture of why these two are tied together.

And how does it ensure `YourValueType[]` can be used without jitting.?

Comment: Probably because 99.9% of collections use an array for storage at some level, so it' reasonable to require that dependency.  Is this causing you an issue or are you just curious?

Comment: @DStandley: Curious.. but again how does it ensure YourValueType[] can be used without jitting.?

Comment: It's not really about `YourValueType[]` *itself*. It's about using it when cast into the corresponding generic interface. `int[]` *doesn't* actually implement `IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator` even though it appears as if it did - the actual implementation is in that mysterious `SZArrayHelper` class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a hack in the JIT, as noted in your quote. When the VM finds that there's a `TypeDependency` on `SZArrayHelper`, it treats the class differently, allowing more efficient code to be used.

Looking at the relevant code in the VM (note that I'm using an older, public version here - not the *actual* .NET VM):

> A call to an array thru IList (or IEnumerable or ICollection) has to be handled specially.
>   These interfaces are "magic" (mostly due to working set concerned - they are created on demand internally
>   even though semantically, these are static interfaces.)

Arrays are a bit of a hack in .NET in the first place. When the generic interfaces were added, this posed a bit of a problem - for example, `int[]` is an `Array`, but it is also a special type, and array of int; this allowed arrays to be generic before *real* generic types were added.

Now, let's see a concrete example. You have an `int[]`, and you want to use it in LINQ. Since `int[]` implements `IEnumerable<int>`, it gives you the full power of LINQ out of the box, and you can write something like this:

```
var positiveNumbers = numbers.Where(i => i > 0);
```

From C#'s point of view, there is no problem. However, from the point of the internals of the VM, this *is* a big problem, because `int[]` doesn't *actually* implement `IEnumerable<int>`! Even after introducing generics to .NET (and C#), arrays are still handled the old way.

The hack is to use `SZArrayHelper` to handle any of those generic methods. So, for example, `Where` calls `GetEnumerator` internally on the `IEnumerable<int>`. The VM finds out that you're trying to call `GetEnumerator` on an array, and instead of virtually dispatching `GetEnumerator` on the array instance, it redirects the call to `SZArrayHelper.GetEnumerator<int>()`.

This is a *huge* hack - if you look at the reference code for `SZArrayHelper`, you'll find tons of warnings - for example, the `GetEnumerator<int>` method is an instance method, but it's `this` argument is actually the *array* (e.g. `int[]`), not `SZArrayHelper`.

But it allows us to treat arrays as if they did actually implement all those generic interfaces - even though they don't :)